# Tensorflow JS : Convert Saved Model from tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to convert a tensorflow saved model to tensorflowjs format using this [converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter).

But this gives me the error `IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at:`

Though my directory has the Saved Model. It has:

.data-****-of-****,
.meta and .index files.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Please post complete stack trace, your directory structure, and where from and with what arguments you are calling the converter.

Comment: Probably what you have is a checkpoint, and not a saved model.  A checkpoint contains the names of the variables and their values.  A saved model additionally contains the model architecture.

Comment: Which command did you use to convert?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when I tried tensorflowjs_converter, I'd like to use tfjs.converters.save_keras_model method in your python implementation as follow.
 Add just one line and that's it then you can import this model from your tensorflowjs project, like I did.

## Example code minist_cnn.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
# add this line
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, './SavedModel')
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```